# failed to route custom packet from ejabberd server 15.09

Tags: function, erlang, ejabberd

I am using ejabberd 15.09 and trying to create a module to send acknowledge message in return for received message , I am getting error while routing this packet.

Error log:

> 2015-10-08 11:10:57.333 [error] <0.437.0>@ejabberd_sm:route:118
>   {function_clause,[{ejabberd_sm,do_route,[{jid,<<"1234567890">>,<<"x.xyz.com">>,<<"asdfgfd23f4">>,<<"1234567890">>,<<"x.xyz.com">>,<<"asdfgfd23f4">>},{jid,<<"0987654321">>,<<"x.xyz.com">>,<<"Bruno.7B81FB19">>,<<"0987654321">>,<<"x.xyz.com">>,<<"Bruno.7B81FB19">>},{xmlelement,"message",[{"id",<<"abc4a">>},{"type","Ack_receipt"},{"from",<<"1234567890@x.xyz.com/asdfgfd23f4">>},{"to",<<"0987654321@x.xyz.com/Bruno.7B81FB19">>}],[{xmlelement,"body",[],[{xmlcdata,<<"ack
>   Message">>}]}]}],[{file,"src/ejabberd_sm.erl"},{line,424}]},{ejabberd_sm,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_sm.erl"},{line,116}]},{ejabberd_local,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_local.erl"},{line,112}]},{ejabberd_router,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_router.erl"},{line,75}]},{mod_ack,log_packet,3,[{file,"src/mod_ack.erl"},{line,32}]},{mod_ack,on_user_send_packet,4,[{file,"src/mod_ack.erl"},{line,28}]},{ejabberd_hooks,safe_apply,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,385}]},{ejabberd_hooks,run_fold1,4,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,368}]}]}
>
> when processing:
>   {{jid,<<"1234567890">>,<<"x.xyz.com">>,<<"asdfgfd23f4">>,<<"1234567890">>,<<"x.xyz.com">>,<<"asdfgfd23f4">>},{jid,<<"0987654321">>,<<"x.xyz.com">>,<<"Bruno.7B81FB19">>,<<"0987654321">>,<<"x.xyz.com">>,<<"Bruno.7B81FB19">>},{xmlelement,"message",[{"id",<<"abc4a">>},{"type","Ack_receipt"},{"from",<<"1234567890@x.xyz.com/asdfgfd23f4">>},{"to",<<"0987654321@x.xyz.com/Bruno.7B81FB19">>}],[{xmlelement,"body",[],[{xmlcdata,<<"ack
>   Message">>}]}]}}

Answer (score 2):

You are formatting an `xmlelement` record. This format is obsolete. Packet record on latest ejabberd are `xmlel` records. You need to update your code to support the new format.

The record format is described here: https://github.com/processone/xml/blob/master/include/xml.hrl